# Getting usercontext supplied is invalid error

Tags: azure, dns, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

i have setup build server on virtual machine in Azure, lets say buildserver is called `vm-build`. I am trying to copy file from build server to another vm called `vm-client` in same subnet and i get error

```
Copying failed for resource : vm-client.cloudapp.net
Failed to connect to the path \\vm-client.cloudapp.net with the user \\domain\username for copying.
The user context supplied is invalid.
```

I am using windows machine file copy functionality from tfs to copy between 2 vm's.

**What i have tried**

Tried to ping vm-client from vm-build with ip address and it returns response. SO in build script i also tried to use ip address instead of dns name but it still gives same error.

**For your information**

when i ping vm with ip address then i get response but when i ping vm with dns name then i get request timeout. I dont think its still issue here.

Comment: Are you able to copy the file from vm-build to vm-client manully?

Comment: Hi DevelopmentIsMyPassion, any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, please double confirm you have follow the requirement of arguments in [Windows Machine File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task.

According to the error `The user context supplied is invalid.`  Make sure your user account has admin permission in `vm-client`

> **Admin Login**
>
> The username of either a domain or a local administrative account on
>   the target host(s).
>
> - Formats such as `domain\username`, `username`, and `machine-name\username`    are supported.
> - UPN formats such as `username@domain.com` and built-in system accounts    such as `NT Authority\System` are not supported.

`\\domain\username` seems not to be a qualify format.

Besides since there are two Azure VMs,  suggest you to use **[Azure File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/azure-file-copy)** task which may do trick.  This task  copy files to Microsoft Azure storage blobs or **virtual machines (VMs)**.

Comment: i have even tried with domain\username and i have admin permissions

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion You could also double check if the port 5986 in windows firewall is enable and windows file sharing abled.  Moreover, suggest you to use **Azure File Copy task** ,if it's hard to trouble shooting the original issue.